# I cannot insert a data with Postgres and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, crud

I'm developing a software with PHP and Postgres. So, I have a problem with insert code:

```
function create(){
    $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " VALUES (" . $this->pess_nome . ")";
            
    $result = pg_query($this->conn, $query);
    
    if($result){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The error message :

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "test" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO pessoa VALUES (test) ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projeto_GPass\objects\pessoa.php on line 26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String values in SQL queries need to be enclosed in apostrophes or quotes. Modify the second line of your code to read:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " VALUES ('" . $this->pess_nome . "')";
```

EDIT: When you use a string value in a query and do not enclose it in quotes `("test")` or apostrophes `('test')`, PostgreSQL takes it as a name of the column, hence the error message.